# WPF: MouseEnter doesn't work on several buttons when mouse is pressed

Tags: wpf, button, mouseenter

I have a list of toggle-buttons in wpf and I want the user to be able to toggle several buttons by dragging over them. To do this, I used the MouseEnter-Event for each button. This does work, when I press the mousebutton outside the buttons and start dragging. But when I press the mousebutton on a button and start dragging, the MouseEnter-Event is only fired for the first button, where I pressed the mousebutton (also none of the other events like mouseover or mousemove are fired).
Here's the code:

```
public void AddButton()
{
    ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton();
    btn.MouseEnter += VisibilityButton_Enter;
    this.gridButtons.Children.Add(btn);
}

private void VisibilityButton_Enter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed || e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        ToggleButton btn = sender as ToggleButton;
        btn.IsChecked = !btn.IsChecked;
    }
}
```

I found a solution to use "drag and drop" and the dragover-event, but I think there must be an easier solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kent mentioned, the `ToggleButton` captures the mouse.  If we handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event ourselves we can prevent that.  The rest is just keeping track of the mouse state so the we don't click twice during a single roll-over.  Here is a behavior you can add to your button to enable roll-over clicking.

First add this namespace:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and the corresponding reference to your project.

Then the XAML looks like this (notice the `RollOverBehavior`):

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <PointCollection>
                <Point/>
                <Point/>
                <Point/>
                <Point/>
                <Point/>
            </PointCollection>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton Width="25" Height="25">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <local:RollOverBehavior/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

and here is the behavior itself:

```
public class RollOverBehavior : Behavior<ToggleButton>
{
    bool mouseOver;
    bool clicked;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) =>
        {
            AssociatedObject.IsChecked = !AssociatedObject.IsChecked;
            e.Handled = true;
        };
        AssociatedObject.MouseEnter += (s, e) =>
        {
            mouseOver = true;
            clicked = false;
        };
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeave += (s, e) =>
        {
            mouseOver = false;
        };
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (mouseOver && !clicked && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                AssociatedObject.IsChecked = !AssociatedObject.IsChecked;
                clicked = true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default behavior of the `ToggleButton` is to capture the mouse when the left mouse button is clicked. Because the mouse is captured, all mouse events are sent to the first `ToggleButton`.

Sounds like what you want to do is override this default behavior such that the mouse isn't captured, but to be honest I couldn't really follow exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with normal `Buttons`. The solution, that worked for me, is to set `e.Handled = true` in the `PreviewMouseButtonDown` event (I implemented this too). It seems, that just by down-click with the mouse, the previous action is not fully handled until the mouse button is released, so the `MouseEnter` event is not able to raise.